# Why does my factorial function always return one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a piece of code to solve a Coderbyte challenge, to calculate a number's factorial. Every time I run it, the factorial generated is one. What am I doing wrong?

```
var num
var array1 = new Array();

function FirstFactorial(num) {     
    for (var i = num; i>0; i--){        // 8 , 7, 6 , 5
        for (var y = 0; y<num ; y++){   // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
        array1[y]=i;       // we have an array that looks like [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
        };
    };
    var sum = 1
    for (var x = 0; x<array1.length; x++){  // now I want to run up that array, reading the #s
        sum = sum * array1[x];
        return sum;
    };
    return sum
};
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You return sum in your last for loop, the first iteration through that loop is going to do the return and the rest of the array isnt going to be processed

Comment: Describe the problem.

Comment: The problem is, as I've said in the beginning, that the code doesn't work. Therefore, "what is the problem?"

Comment: Thanks @patrickevans !!! How can I fix this?

Comment: @Kvera As per Stackoverflow's quality requirements, "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: "code doesn't work" is not sufficient.   have you demonstrated why you think it might?  please put a minimal amount of effort into the question if you expect people to help you for free.

Comment: Kvera, have a look at the updates I made to the question. It's a good idea to check before posting that you have (1) the minimalist code required to exhibit the problem (you had this, your code), (2) what you wanted to happen (you had this, "get a factorial") and what actually happened (you always get one - this is the bit I added and the missing "specific problem" that thefourtheye mentioned). Now, as a question, it's hopefully more acceptable to the swarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues.

1/ This is minor but, when you multiply two numbers, you get a product, not a sum.

2/ You returned the value from *within* the loop which would mean, even if you fixed the other problems, it would return prematurely without having multiplied all the numbers.

3/ Your nested loop does not fill your array the way you describe, you should check it after population. Think about your loops expressed as pseudo-code:

```
for i = num downto 1 inclusive:
    for y = 0 to num-1 inclusive:
        array1[y] = i
```

You can see that the inner loop is populating the entire array with the value of the current `i`. So the *last* iteration of the outer loop, where `i` is one, sets the entire array to ones.

4/ In any case, you don't *need* an array to store all the numbers from 1 to `n`, just use the numbers 1 to `n` directly. Something like (again, pseudo-code):

```
def fact(n):
    prod = 1
    for i = 2 to n inclusive:
        prod = prod * i
    return prod
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a much easier way to calculate the factorial of a number.

```js
function factorial(num)
{
 if(num === 1)
 {
   return num;
 }
 return num * factorial(num - 1);
}
```

However to fix your code you need to fix the initial loop that loads the numbers into the array. as well as remove the return statement in the bottom loop. Like so.

```js
function FirstFactorial(num) {     
    for (var i = num; i>0; i--) {
        array1[num - i] = i;
    };
    var sum = 1
    for (var x = 0; x < array1.length; x++){  // now I want to run up that array, reading the #s
        sum = sum * array1[x];
    };
    return sum
};
```

Comment: honerlawd, thank you very much for your attention. Could you please explain to me why the initial loop was wrong?

Comment: Your outer loop at the top worked fine and counted down respectively from the number to 1. However, your inner loop counted up from 0 to 7. So basically you were filling each index in the array with whatever number the inner loop was on and overwriting all of the previous numbers. If that makes sense.

Comment: Isn't that what it was supposed to do? Store array1[0] = 8, array1[1] = 7, and so on? Sorry, of course I am a newbie.

Comment: On the first iteration it does this `[4, 4, 4, 4]` on the next iteration it does `[3, 3, 3, 3]` and so on then stops at `[1, 1, 1, 1]` because the outer loop terminates when the value of `i = 0;`

Comment: Not quite. On first outer iteration, it sets all array values to `num`. Then it sets them all to `num - 1`, and so on, eventually setting them all to `1` on the final outer iteration.

Comment: @honerlawd, s'ok, you changed it to be correct as I was entering my comment. As it turns out, my comment could equally be directed at Kvera's last comment as it could have been to your now-fixed one, so I'll leave it in :-)

Comment: I don't see why... everytime i goes down 1 unit, y goes up one unit. Can't figure why it "eventually" sets "them all to 1 on the final outer iteration. :(